# Slim 3 - Error is not shown

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

I am trying to use [zeuxisoo/slim-whoops](https://github.com/zeuxisoo/php-slim-whoops)  to show errors, but for some reason I am only getting white screen without any message show. This is the code I am using (I don't know if it does matter, I am using quick PHP host (php -S localhost:8000):

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App([

    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'debug'               => true,
        'whoops.editor'       => 'sublime',
    ]

]);

$app->add(new \Zeuxisoo\Whoops\Provider\Slim\WhoopsMiddleware);
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure that your file begins with `<?php` and that after your `$app->add(...);` you call `$app->run();`:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App([

    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'debug'               => true,
        'whoops.editor'       => 'sublime',
    ]

]);

$app->add(new \Zeuxisoo\Whoops\Provider\Slim\WhoopsMiddleware);
$app->run();
```